# Geocoder Gem: How to use between two different models?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, pagination

I'm using the [Geocoder](https://github.com/alexreisner/geocoder) and [Will Paginate](https://github.com/mislav/will_paginate) gems to sort my results based on the distance from a user's location and a kids' mom's address. My models are like this:

```
class User
 has_many :kids
 geocoded_by :address
end

class Kid
  belongs_to :mom
  belongs_to :dad
end

class Mom
  has_many :kids
  has_many :dads, through: :kids
  geocoded_by :address
end

class Dad
  has_many :kids
  has_many :moms, through: :kids
end
```

Now, I'm trying to use the correct scope that I will use the `Users.address` and compare it to the `Kids.moms.addresses`

```
def show
 @dad = Dad.find(params[:id])
 @user_location = current_user.address
 @kids = @dad.kids.near(@user_location, 100).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 25).order(created_at: :desc)
end
```

This gives me the error:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `address' for nil:NilClass:
  app/controllers/dads_controller.rb:14:in `show'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:189:in `process_action'
  actionpack (4.0.2) lib/action_controller/metal/rendering.rb:10:in `process_action'
.......
```

Any suggestions?

---

**UPDATE**

So far I've done this now:

```
class ApplicationController
  before_filter :set_user_location

  private

  def set_user_location
    if signed_in?
      @user_location = current_user.address
    end
  end
end

class DadsController

def show
  @dad = Dad.find(params[:id])
  @kids = @dad.kids.joins(:mom).merge(Mom.near(@user_location, 100)).order(name: :asc, created_at: :desc).paginate(page: params[:page], per_page: 25)
end
```

The code above gets the current users address to work (using Devise) but now I get the error:

```
ActiveModel::MissingAttributeError

missing attribute: birthday
```

For all of my Kids attributes on the page.

```
<% @kids.each do |kid| %>
   <%= kid.birthday %>
   <%= kid.name %>
   <% if kid.upkeep.present? %>
     <%= kid.upkeep %>
     <%= kid.upkeep_size %> 
   <% end %>      
   <%= kid.age %>
   <%= kid.favorite_color %>
<% end %>
```

I think this is because it thinks Mom has the same attributes as the kid. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how you can do it with Geocoder:

```
def show
  @dad = Dad.find(params[:id])
    near = Mom.near(@user_location, 100, :select => "kids.*")
  @kids = @dad.kids.joins(:mom).merge(near).order(name: :asc, created_at: :desc).page(params[:page])
end
```

The `:select` option is what I needed to add.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that `Kid`s aren't geocoded themselves, so you can't use the `near` scope.

Something like this should get you close:

```
@dad.kids.joins(:mom).merge(Mom.near("San Francisco, CA, US")).paginate(...).order(...)
```

[Docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/SpawnMethods.html#method-i-merge)

**EDIT**

Based on your updated question, it looks like `current_user` is `nil`. Once you fix that and combine it with the query above, you should be good.

Comment: Appreciate it. I actually needed to change my question as it asked the wrong thing. I'm trying to start from the users location and than sort by distance. Take a look at my question now. How would I use  the current users address and show results starting from there?

Comment: OK, now I know what I'm getting it. I want to compare the address of the User to the `kid.mom.address` in the `@kids` loop.